# Does Raspbian keep a security log file, and what is its location?

Tags: networking, vpn, security, login

I set up an OpenVPN server on my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian and am wondering if there is a log file of security events that I can look at.  I'm curious because I want to know if there are login attempts via the now forwarded port that I should be looking at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi OS uses **systemd**, so you will find logs in its journal. It also contains the logging from the OpenVPN server. Look at it to the current boot with:

```
rpi ~$ journalctl --boot=0 --pager-end
```

You can filter it to the service:

```
rpi ~$ journalctl --boot=0 --unit=openvpn.service
```

Comment: I tried this and was given a hint:Hint: "You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in the 'systemd-journal' group can see all messages. Pass -q to
      turn off this notice.
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions."  So I then ran with sudo and got output.  Router advertisements but not anything from OpenVPN yet.

Comment: @ErikS Add user **pi** to group `systemd-journal` with `sudo adduser pi systemd-journal`, logout and login. I don't know how do you setup OpenVPN. Maybe you don't use its systemd services? That's default with installation from the RaspiOS repository. I have tested [simple openVPN with static keys](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/98186/79866) and found its output in the journal.